# Datatable Individual Column Search with Select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, datatable

I can make individual searches with select boxes in a datatable but I just want to make this thing for one column, other columns are unnecessary. For example, I just want to make active this select box thing on second and third columns.

I found [this URL](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) but it didn't help me. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $("#example tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {
        var select = $('<select><option value="">Lütfen seçiniz</option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
            .on( 'change', function () {
                var val = $(this).val();

                table.column( i )
                    .search( val ? '^'+$(this).val()+'$' : val, true, false )
                    .draw();
            } );

        table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: @Skynet: again, I remind you to fix other issues in the post which are obvious, such as unneeded saluations ("Thank you"), the incorrect code indentation and other formatting issues in the post. Editing bumps the post to the top of the homepage and doing this just to add a tag is a waste of time.

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy many times tried but site is not let me rectify them by saying it's not enough. So here I can't do anything about it.

Comment: @Skynet: then edit the other text too, fix a bit of spelling in the other parts of the post then it will let you. I've already done it for you this time, take a look at the edit summary to see what I've changed.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a way to solve.

You can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $("#example tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {

    if(i == 0){ //Create just one SelectBox
            var select = $('<select class='+i+'><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {

                    var val = $(this).val();

                    table.column( 0 ) //Only the first column
                        .search( val ? '^'+$(this).val()+'$' : val, true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            table.column( 0 ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
            } );
    } 
});
} );
```